# Tangent equation of a plane that contains a line

Tags: linear-algebra, spheres

Find equations for all the planes that intersect the $y$-axis at $y = 1$ and the $z$-axis at $z = 2$, and are tangent
to the sphere $$( − 2)^2 + ^2 + ^2 = 4.$$ Do not use calculus.

So basically we have the sphere $$( − 2)^2 + ^2 + ^2 = 4$$
and I'm looking for tangent planes that intersect the points $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,2)$ and that will create a line and im looking for planes that are tangent to the sphere and contain both those points.

So far I only have the $x=0$ plane because of inspection and I'm not sure about the rest of the planes whether there are only a few more planes or if there is a region on the sphere where the tangent planes contain the line. If so I cant seem to find the range of the values because I'm stuck figuring out how to express a point on the plane as a general point of the sphere.

Not really sure what to do here I've spent 5 hours racking my brain trying to do this.

Comment: What does it means "Do not use calculus"? Can you use the formula for the distance of the plane from the center of the sphere?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

the planes passing through the given points have equation
$$ax+y+\frac{1}{2}z=1$$
and are tangent to the given sphere if the [distance](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html) from the center of the sphere is the radius of the sphere.

Comment: Do not use calculus probably means the partial differentiation method or something

Comment: Also does the 'a' in ax+y+(1/2)z = 1 mean the same a in (a,b,c)